# tRPC: Query and Mutation on the same route

Tags: trpc

I'm migrating standard REST Api to tRPC. I had the endpoints:

- GET `/api/auth` (get auth info about a user)
- POST `/api/auth` (auth a user)

In the tRPC router, I cannot add `query` and `mutation` to the same route. Obviously, I have an error
`TS1117: An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name.` for an object I pass to the router.

```
auth: authedProcedure
  .query(({ ctx }) => ({ account: ctx.account })),

auth: publicProcedure
  .mutation(({ ctx }) => ({ foo: 'bar' })),
```

Can `query` and `mutation` be combined for one route (using different procedures)?

How to deal with this case?

Comment: Give them different names.

Comment: @super, of course, it will work. I'm asking if there is something built-in for these cases.

Comment: You typically don't think in terms of routes and methods when using RPC. There are just methods with names. So `GET/POST/PUT` to `/foo` would typically become `getFoo/createFoo/updateFoo` or something similar. I would just try to give them some descriptive name to help document what the difference is between the two.

Comment: @super It's exactly what I realized recently. RPC are just typical functions and I don't need to care about GET and POST. Hard to switch mentally after 15 years :) Thanks for your help!